# Localhost showing live WordPress website with 'localhost' in the URL bar

Tags: wordpress, apache2

So i've downloaded my repo and i'm working on the website on my localhost. Problem is though, even though it says 'localhost' in the URL bar. I'm seeing the live version of the site in my browser.

I've looked at .htaccess, wp-config.php and wp-config-local.php. They all seem fine. I've added site and site_url variables to wp-config-local.php.

I've also cleared browser cache and purged the server cache. I've had a look in resolv.conf as well as /etc/hosts. I've reloaded apache2.

Any ideas?

```
localhost: cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1       dara-HP-Pavilion-Notebook-15-bc5xxx

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: what appears in the url bar will be the request you make to view it, if you're running a copy of the site on your local computer, that's going to be localhost unless you make an entry in /etc/hosts redirecting the live domain to your local computer and then use that domain to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

I scrubbed the repo and restarted apache. Worked.

As in...

```
rm -rf /git_repo  [warning this deletes entire repo]
git init 
...clone your repo from githost
```

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

I'll update this if i'm missing anything...